# What is the difference between canonical_scan_matcher and polar_scan_matcher?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My main question after having read quickly the ROS documentation is the difference beetween the canonical and the polar scan matching.

I know there must be answers in the related documentations  :
http://www.irrc.monash.edu.au/adiosi/downloads.html
[http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~andrea/research/sw/csm.html](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Eandrea/research/sw/csm.html)

But, it'll help to have a synthesis of differences (I imagin it is about performance on axis, robustness, consumed cpu ...) on the scan_tools main page. Just some words for newbies like me in this domain :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9938/what-is-the-difference-between-canonical_scan_matcher-and-polar_scan_matcher-?/) by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 352 on 2011-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Willy,

The canonical and polar scan matcher ROS packages are wrappers around two different scan matching algorithms. The ROS packages behave in the same way in terms of what the input and output is. This means you should be able to use them interchangeably.

Since the algorithms are different, I recommend trying them both, and seeing which one gives you better performance. In our lab, we chose to go with the canonical scan matcher, although we got good results with both. Whichever one you choose, take a look at the parameters - some tweaks here and there can make a big difference.

In terms of specific differences in the algorithms - as far as I remember, CSM uses a point-to-line metric and works in Cartesian space, while PSM uses a point-to-point metric and works in polar space. Beyond that, I'd suggest you refer to the papers

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-05-12**:
thanks for this anwser